# Can I use the Ceylon language with RoboVM (iOS)?

Tags: jvm, robovm, jvm-languages, ceylon

I'm getting lately interested in the JVM, thanks to this awesome language called Ceylon. So if RoboVM enables you to write Java targetting iOS, I'm wondering if there could be a way to use Ceylon with RoboVM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After quick look on documentation http://docs.robovm.com/user/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/#_the_bytecode_compiler.

> By consuming Java bytecode rather than Java source code the RoboVM ahead-of-time compiler can, at least in theory, be used with any JVM language that compiles down to bytecode. Scala, Clojure and Kotlin are JVM languages already known to work. Another benefit with this approach is that RoboVM can be used with 3rd party libraries in standard JAR files without any need for the original source code enabling the use of proprietary and closed-source libraries.

I see it is compiling Java bytecode into native app.

Ceylon compiles to Java bytecode, therefore you should be able to compile Ceylon to Java bytecode using ceylon compiler and later compile it to native iOS app using RoboVM.

RoboVM supports Java 7, which is using by Ceylon 1.1 compiler. In future versions Ceylon may require newer version of Java what may lead to compatibility issues if RoboVM won't keep up.

Follow Ceylon Java interoperation manual to be able to use RoboVM classes from Ceylon.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I guess it's not complete because Ceylon is not just another JVM language at the bytecode level because AFAIU it has a runtime, possibly for the non-JVM-compatible language features

Comment: Yes Ceylon has a runtime, and you can figure out which jars to add to your classpath with `ceylon classpath`.